# MapView with LeftTop corner round and RightTop corner angled

Tags: xcode, swift

So this is what I have so far:

```
    let indentTopToLeft: CGFloat    = 50
    let indentTopToBottom: CGFloat  = 100

    let path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 3, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200-indentTopToLeft, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200, indentTopToBottom)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200 , 150)//4
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 150)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 3)
    //The rounded goes here. But I don't know how.
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 3, 0)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path
    self.mapView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

[image]

Now I need a round corner between this two points but I don't know how, Please help.

```
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 3)
//HERE
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 3, 0)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. It's not clear where you want the arc added at. Maybe you should include a graphic/picture of what you want? Did you see the additional functions `CGPathAddArc`, `CGPathAddRelativeArc`, and `CGPathAddArcToPoint`? I would be be using one of those to add curved corners.

Comment: I added some graphics. I think I need to use a Arc too but I have no idea how. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, but the most straight forward is likely to use the `CGPathAddArc` function.  Note that doing so leaves you at point 0,3 so there is no need for the code that adds a line to that point.  I would expect the modified drawing code to look like this:

```
let indentTopToLeft: CGFloat     = 50
let indentTopToBottom: CGFloat   = 100
let topLeftCornerRadius: CGFloat = 3

let path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, topLeftCornerRadius, 0)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200-indentTopToLeft, 0)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200, indentTopToBottom)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 200 , 150)//4
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 150)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, topLeftCornerRadius)
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, topLeftCornerRadius, topLeftCornerRadius, topLeftCornerRadius, CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI), CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI_2), false)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
```

The parameters of `CGPathAddArc` are well documented; after the nil we have the x and then y position of the center point of the arc, the arc radius, the starting angle and ending angle (in radians), and then a value indicating if it should be draw clockwise or counter-clockwise.  Of note is that I always find the clockwise value and the start and end angles to not be what I expect - this is likely because `CoreGraphics` has a different origin (bottom left) than `UIKit` (top left), but I can't explain it for certain.